# Create order sales_email_order_items html file

Tags: email, magento

I am creating order from backend in magento and user is getting email of order details, in that email product details are coming from variable `sales_email_order_items`. I want to modify that table(`totals` of order tax, `subtotal` etc.). I have tried changing in file

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/email/order/items.phtml
```

but it do not shows any effect in the email. I want to know from which file that totals content is coming.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the template path hints and then place an order, the template path hints will also be displayed in the email.
Still you should have a look at this file 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order`
. Probably it might help you.

Comment: Should I enable template path hints of backend or frontend?

Comment: enable template path hints for frontend

Comment: Changing in frontend/default/theme-name/template/tax/order/tax.phtml is getting used for tax. If I change in this file will it affect any other part of magento?

Comment: yes it will affect in all the places where tax is applied